# Coin toss simulation/game in Java

Tags: java, simulation

I'm currently doing a course in computer science which is technically for beginners, but I feel all the assignments they are giving me are more complicated than I can handle.

This assignment asks me to make a coin toss simulation. Three people play the game and each of them has specific requirements to win:

- One wins if there are 2 results head and the total number of tosses
  is even
- One wins if there are 2 results tails and the total number of tosses is even
- One wins if there are 2 results tails OR heads and the total number of tosses is odd

What I should do is run an experiment 300 times. Each time I should determine who of the three won and how many times. And I'm really stuck. I barely have any code but I do have an very basic idea of what the code should be like, but I can't put it into Java language.

For my assignment, I need to display the binary sequence that caused a person to win.

My idea:

1. Initialize a counter (1, 2, 3) for every person so that I can keep track of how many times they win
2. Initialize a head count and a tails count to keep track of the randomly generated sequence
3. Use a for loop for practically the whole experiment. There should be an outer loop that defines the experiment should be run 300 times and the inner loop should contain the if statements that check who has won. There should be a counter in every if statement, so that I can update it for every person. And I need a System.out.println(); to print every single result of the experiment.
4. Print the final outcome of the experiment, using the previously determined counters

**EDIT:** 
I've tried to change what everyone said and it does look better now, thanks! But it's still not doing what it's supposed to do and I wonder why. I run the code and I only get one output; not the 300 times I want it to run. Furthermore, the counters at the end don't hold the information about who has won, they reset every single time. And sometimes two people win, while that should not be possible. Could anyone clarify this?

**EDIT:**
This is another update of the code. I believe it does run 300 times now! A problem now is the output. Sometimes it says; 1 Bernie wins, while you obviously need at least 2 results for Bernie to win. Also, it says 1 Penny wins, while that also shouldn't be possible. Did I mess something up in my if statements?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment3e
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{                
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int counter3 = 0;

    Random coin = new Random();


    for(int i = 0; i <= 300; i++){
        int headCount = 0;
        int tailsCount = 0;
        for(int coinToss = 0; coinToss <= 3; coinToss++){
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(random);

          boolean result = coin.nextBoolean();
          if(result){
              headCount++;
              }
              else{
                  tailsCount++;
                  }
         if(headCount == 2 && binary.length() % 2 ==0){
                //Amy wins
                counter1 = counter1 + 1;
                System.out.println(binary + " Amy wins.");
            }
            else if(tailsCount == 2 && binary.length() % 2 == 0){
                //Penny wins
                counter2 = counter2 + 1;
                System.out.println(binary + " Penny wins.");
            }
            else if(headCount == 2 || tailsCount == 2 && binary.length() % 2 != 0){
                //Bernie wins
                counter3 = counter3 + 1;
                System.out.println(binary + " Bernie wins.");
            }
         }
      }
        System.out.println("Amy wins " + counter1 + " times.");
        System.out.println("Penny wins " + counter2 + " times.");
        System.out.println("Bernie wins " + counter3 + " times.");
}

}
```

Comment: So you want to basically stop the `for` loops? You can use break for that

Comment: you don't the `Random dice` if you use `Math.random()` and never use `dice`

Comment: Remove this useless binary string. And use the `coinToss`value, not the `binary.length()`, that doesn't make sense

Comment: I tried removing the binary string, but it doesn't work. For my assignment, I need to display the binary sequence that caused a person to win. So if I remove binary, I can't display it anymore. Also, I'm not really sure if the head/tails counter works correctly.

Comment: I edited my answer and your question to add this requirement.

Answer (score 4):

You almost got it right.

This part is not relevant anymore since OP add a requirement in comments.

> Your second `for` loop only need to run a maximum of 3 times as there will be at least 2 heads or 2 tails, not 10.
>
> **Edit:** you can do it with a maximun of 2 tosses: if there is 1 head and 1 tail, the winner is the 3rd player (`Bernie`)
>
> Now, on each iteration, you can draw a random decimal number, between 0 and 1 and assume if it's over `0.5` it's a head so you increment the `headCount`, else you increment the `tailCount`. Then you can perform the  test on the counters (and the number of tosses).
>
> It's easier than using a binary String.

Edit:
To answer your comment:
Look where you initialized the `headCount`and `tailCount`. Remember that once one has won, those counters must be reset.

As it's homework, I won't post code :)

**Edit:**
OP jsut add a comment stating he need to print the sequence that lead to the result of each game.

We assume a binary `1` is a head, and a `0` is a tail. You need to toss the coin 3 times to know the sequence if `Bernie` wins. So the integer value `random` which is converted in binary string only need to be made of 3 bits (1 bit = 1 toss).

`random` can only take values between 0 and 7.

As you get all values in one shot, you don't need the `coinToss` for loop anymore. All you need to do is to check if the beginning of the binary string matches any win pattern (`11` for 2 heads, `00` for 2 tails, else Bernie wins)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the for-comment and the 0.5! Now I still have the problem that my program still says someone has won even if it outputs only one 1, while that shouldn't be the case. And I can't seem to get it running for the 300 times I intended to; it just gives me 3 cases now.

Comment: As I don't know how you implemented the modifications, I can't help you more.

Comment: I uploaded the code that I changed, sorry, I had forgotten to do that!

Comment: why the third loop? You already toss the coin 3 times in the second loop but because of the third one and this binary  string, it's just like each toss contains a random amount of coins. And you still need to set the head and tail count to 0 **before** starting a new game, i.e. on each of the 300 iterations

Comment: Now that you mention it, that does indeed not make a lot of sense. I tried to run my code again, but now it sometimes outputs only a 1 and declares someone has won. Also, my total amount of wins is now 340, 91 and 80. That 's clearly too much. Wow, this is really confusing!

Comment: Okay, but how do I make sure the random/binary string prints at least three values? Because now it sometimes just prints 10 and 1 and these do not meet the requirements. I now edited to this:
                String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(random);
              
             for(int j = 0; j < binary.length(); j++){
                 String letter = binary.substring(j, j + 1);
                 
                 if("1".equals(letter)){
                     headCount++;
                     }
                     else{
                         tailsCount++;
                         }

Comment: Leading 0 are omitted. Either you add them manually or you just check the `random`integer value and deduce the result (and sequence). Also , there are methods to test if strings [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29), [ends](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29), or [starts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) with a sequence

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of things I'm noticing here:

- You don't update `headCount` or `tailCount` anywhere.  This should be what you're using to keep track of the number of coin flips.

  When you go back to reuse these in subsequent loops, be sure to zero them out again.
- You're using a very wide range for your result, when a simple `nextBoolean` would be all that needs to suffice.  You could use it as this in your loop:

  ```
  boolean result = coin.nextBoolean(); // this renames dice to coin
  if(result) {
      headCount++;
  } else {
      tailCount++;
  }
  ```
- The total number of tosses is *always* the current iteration's current value (plus 1).  So, in your case, you could simply replace `sum` with `j`, but you'd want to give it a more meaningful name, like `coinTosses` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my code. I'm still having trouble with it though, because it lets more than one person win in one round. It also says 1 is valid to win, while I thought I had established it was not. Nobody should be able to win with only one flip. I'm stuck on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Random() object anyways for the coin nextBoolean(), why not replace the `int random = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;` with `int random = coin.nextInt([range here])`?